# pandas Series.value_counts returns inconsistent order for equal count strings

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy, counter

When I run the code below:

```
s = pandas.Series(['c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'])
print(s.value_counts())
```

Sometimes I get this:

```
a    2
b    2
c    1
dtype: int64
```

And sometimes I get this:

```
b    2
a    2
c    1
dtype: int64
```

e.g. the index order returned for equivalent counts is not the same. I couldn't reproduce this if the Series values are integers instead of strings.

Why does this happen, and what is the most efficient way to get the same index order every time?

I want it to still be sorted in descending order by counts, but to be consistent in the order of equivalent-counts items.

I'm running Python 3.7.0 and pandas 0.23.4

Comment: the values you get are sorted according to the count. In your case, both a and b have the same frequency, therefore, the output you get is different based on the CPU allocation maybe.

Comment: See the related issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15833).

Comment: @user2285236, thanks, the place where the order changes is pinpointed there: "The order is changed from pandas/hashtable.pyx.build_count_table_object(). Resizing of the pymap moves the entries by hashing values."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options to sort consistently given a series:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c'])
c = s.value_counts()
```

#### sort by index

Use [`pd.Series.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
res = c.sort_index()

a    2
b    1
c    2
dtype: int64
```

#### sort by count (arbitrary for ties)

For descending counts, do nothing, as this is the default. Otherwise, you can use [`pd.Series.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), which defaults to `ascending=True`. In either case, you should make no assumptions on how ties are handled.

```
res = c.sort_values()

b    1
c    2
a    2
dtype: int64
```

More efficiently, you can use `c.iloc[::-1]` to reverse the order.

#### sort by count and then by index

You can use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to sort by count and *then* by index. Note the reverse order, i.e. `-c.values` is used *first* for sorting.

```
res = c.iloc[np.lexsort((c.index, -c.values))]

a    2
c    2
b    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `reindex` after `value_counts`

```
df.value_counts().reindex(df.unique())
Out[353]: 
a    1
b    1
dtype: int64
```

Update

```
s.value_counts().sort_index().sort_values()
```

Comment: This undoes the ordering by counts if not all items occur with the same frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sort_index`:

```
print(df.value_counts().sort_index())
```

Output:

```
a    1
b    1
dtype: int64
```

Please see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) if you want to use parameters (like `ascending=True` etc.)

`sort_index` vs `reindex(df.unique())` (as suggested by @Wen) seem to be perform quite similar:

```
df.value_counts().sort_index():         1000 loops, best of 3: 636 µs per loop
df.value_counts().reindex(df.unique()): 1000 loops, best of 3: 880 µs per loop
```

Comment: This also undoes the ordering by counts if not all items occur with the same frequency.

Comment: Ok you slightly changed the question I see. Does jpp's answer work for you?