# Pandas returning inconsistent count of column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called 'results' and it holds either a 1 or 0. I'd like to get the number of 1's and 0's for testing purposes but I'm getting some strange results.

I initially do:

```
df.sort_values(by='results', axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

then:

```
num_ones = df['results'].value_counts().values[1]
num_zeroes = df['results'].value_counts().values[0]
print("num_ones: " + str(num_ones))
print("num_zeroes: " + str(num_zeroes))
```

Output:

```
num_ones: 3610
num_zeroes: 51500
```

Right away I see the values are flipped. num_ones actually holds the number of 0's and vice versa.

I then do

```
df1 = df.loc[df['results'] == 1]
print('Ones: ' + str(df1.shape[0]))
df0 = df.loc[df['results'] == 0]
print('zeros: ' + str(df0.shape[0]))
```

Output:

```
Ones: 51500
zeros: 3610
```

and the results are correct. What could be causing the initial approach to not work?

I notice that this is not an issue with smaller datasets with <5k rows.

Comment: what is your small df look like , how many 1 and 0 contains  ?

Answer (score 1):

What we usually do by using `.loc` since the result become `index` after `value_counts`

```
num_ones = df['results'].value_counts().loc[1]
num_zeroes = df['results'].value_counts().loc[0]
print("num_ones: " + str(num_ones))
print("num_zeroes: " + str(num_zeroes))
```

Since `value_counts` default the `sort=True` and you 1 counts more than 0 so , `pandas` sorted the 1 above 0

For Example

```
s=pd.Series([0,1,1]) #assuming it is well sorted
s.value_counts()
Out[4]: 
1    2
0    1
dtype: int64
```

And if you do `.value[0]` will output 1's count

Comment: Do you know that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933763/pandas-series-value-counts-returns-inconsistent-order-for-equal-count-strings so your bottom thing may well be wrong sometimes

Comment: @U10-Forward what you mean ?

Comment: I mean `value_counts` doesn't always keep it's order

Comment: @U10-Forward a h , good point and nice search , update in that post

Comment: Haha i thought you would know, first time we realized :P

Answer (score 1):

`values[1]` gets the index `1` (second element) which may not be `1`, here it's `0`, so you need to do `loc` as in @WenYoBen's answer, or a condition:

```
>>> vc = df['result'].value_counts()
>>> vc[vc.index.eq(1)].item()
5
>>>
```

Comment: This makes sense. But I was wondering why I don't see the problem for smaller datasets.

Comment: @Brosef That means that `0` is the first value of the dataframe!

Comment: @Brosef There is no correlation between the problem and the size of the dataframe

Comment: I want to believe that there's no correlation, but this was not happening when using smaller datasets. Also, I'm calling `df.sort_values(by='results', axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=True) ` at the start, so 1's should always be at index 0.

Comment: @Brosef Are you sure that there are only `1`s and `0`s in the dataframe?

Comment: 2 for both small and large data sets.

Comment: @Brosef Please retry it.

Comment: @Brosef Can you first give the two answers an up-vote? :-)

Comment: I did retry it - still 2

Comment: @Brosef Strange, that shouldn't happen

Comment: maybe 'value_counts()' doesn't preserve order?

Comment: @Brosef Yup you're right, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933763/pandas-series-value-counts-returns-inconsistent-order-for-equal-count-strings, that's the issue, at least no correlation between the size and the problem

Answer (score 1):

While @WeNYoBen and @U10-Forward have mentioned the proper way of accessing the values, the main cause of the issue was that in the smaller datasets there are more 0's while in the larger datasets there are more 1's and `value_counts()` is in descending order.