# Pandas Python - value_counts() or idxmax() returns different value each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Series which consists of a list of some random products. This is what it looks like if I print the describe:

```
<bound method NDFrame.describe of 176                                     reversible jacket
231                       the north face resolve 2 jacket
234                             columbia pike lake jacket
279     girl's 7-16 knitworks skater belted dress faux...
303                                flocked quilted jacket
                              ...
7665    tommy hilfiger big boys wayne colorblocked bas...
7685    men's toronto raptors columbia red flash forwa...
7796    the north face uo exclusive topography fanorak...
7809    lauren ralph lauren solid ultraflex classic-fi...
7922    tommy hilfiger sport faux-sherpa colorblocked ...
Name: desc, Length: 146, dtype: object>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I have these 2 statements after this

```
max_occurence_prod = prod.where(prod.str.len() > 1)
curr_product = max_occurence_prod.value_counts().idxmax()
```

However, every time I run this piece of code, the value of `curr_product` seems to be different. For instance, the first time I ran this code, the value of `curr_product` was "`diamond quilted packable jacket`", the second time it was "`boys' logan jacket`"

From my understanding the `value_counts()` function should return a Series which contains the count of unique values. If this Series is returned as the exact same each time, then shouldn't the `idxmax()` return the same corresponding value as well? I can't seem to figure out why it would return a different value each time.

Here is the overall code

```
max_occurence_prod = prod.where(prod.str.len() > 1)
curr_product = max_occurence_prod.value_counts().idxmax()
#new value is printed each time
print(max_occurence_prod.value_counts().idxmax())
```

Apologies if anything is unclear, I'm fairly new to Python and Pandas

Comment: Please include a complete reproducible example. Also, why do you use `prod.where(prod.str.len() > 1)` instead of `prod[prod.str.len() > 1]`?

Comment: I require a series and not a list. The reason I'm doing that is because I require only those rows that have a string length > 1.

Comment: `prod[prod.str.len() > 1]` is doing precisely what you want.

Comment: `prod[prod.str.len() > 1]` would return a list, and not a Series. I require a Series

Comment: Wrong. `prod[prod.str.len() > 1]` evaluates to a series. Did you try?

Comment: You're right, I executed `[prod.str.len() > 1]` instead of `prod[prod.str.len() > 1]`
But the results are same, It didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there has been [previous issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933763/pandas-series-value-counts-returns-inconsistent-order-for-equal-count-strings) regarding how pandas `value_counts()` deals with tied values, in an inconsistent way.

As for `idxmax()` the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html#pandas.Series.idxmax) states clearly:

> If multiple values equal the maximum, the first row label with that value is returned.

I am afraid the amount of information you provide is not enough for me to generate a full example with your data but here is an attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col_1':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],'col_2':['one','two','three','one','two','three']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for i in range(3):
    print(df['col_1'].value_counts().idxmax())
```

Run once in command:

```
c
c
c
```

Second time in command:

```
b
b
b
```

Third time:

```
a
a
a
```

The conclusion is that you are getting different values each time due to `value_counts()` and not `idxmax()`. Some solutions to make it always replicable is to use `sort_index()` too so that the output is not dependent on a random value. For example:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(df['col_1'].value_counts().sort_index().idxmax())
```

Returns always:

```
a
a
a
```

Comment: You're right! To get more consistent results, all I had to do was
`max_occurence_prod.value_counts().sort_index().idxmax()`
Thanks!

Comment: My pandas version is 0.25.3, seems like this has been an issue since version 0.23.4 at least